# A loader screen in java that doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make a loader screen in java. So far I've managed to successfully make a splash screen for my program, the splash screen works fine.
I've used the same code to create the loader but when I call the object only the sleep part works, I mean nothing really appears on the screen.

```
public class IL extends JWindow {
Image L=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("L.png");
ImageIcon LI=new ImageIcon(L);

public IL (){
try  
{  
setSize(LI.getIconWidth(),LI.getIconHeight());  
setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
show();  
Thread.sleep(10000);  
dispose();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread with that `sleep`, essentially preventing it from displaying anything.

You should use a timer for this. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and the Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) API docs. You use a timer to do the hide/dispose after however much time you want. You could also use that timer to display a progress bar or animate your loader page.

Comment: Thanks, that's right I removed the sleep and it is now working well.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had one handy, a complete implementation.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Splash extends JWindow {

    public Splash(Image image, int millis){
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(image);
        add(new JLabel(icon));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ActionListener hideAction = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                dispose();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(millis, hideAction);
        setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(
            new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg"));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Splash(image, 6000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```